# Dynamic Table binding

Tags: sapui5

Please suggest. Table binding does not work.
Model Data and may change:

```
​{ "TestCloudEnvRO": [ { "pipelineName": "RP1", "cycles": [ "cy1", "cycle1", "RP1cy2", "cyc2", "crCycle" ] }, { "pipelineName": "RP2", "cycles": [ "BP1-c2", "bp2-cy" ] }, { "pipelineName": "RPlocal", "cycles": [ "cyclelocal" ] }, { "pipelineName": "rp1234", "cycles": [ "cyclert" ] }, { "pipelineName": "RPTEST", "cycles": [ "BPTEST1" ] }, { "pipelineName": "rp123", "cycles": [ "cytr" ] } ] }
```

View

```
<Table id="idtrlAllPipelines" alternateRowColors="true">
                                            
                    <columns>
                        <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                            <Text text="Release Pipeline Cycles"/>
                        </Column>
</columns>
```

Controller

```
var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({ cells: [ new sap.m.Text({ text: "{getHist>pipelineName}" }) ] }); this.byId("idtrlAllPipelines").setModel(oModelEnv, "getHist");
```

this.byId("idtrlAllPipelines").bindAggregation("items", { path: "getHist>/TestCloudEnvRO", template: oTemplate, templateShareable: true } );

It does not load any items in the table.
But this works at View. I have to replace this with /TestCloudEnvRO with selected key of Icon tab filter, so the above should work. Please suggest.

```
<Table items="{path: 'getHist>/TestCloudEnvRO'}" id="idtrlAllPipelines" alternateRowColors="true">
```

Comment: For every iconTab, you should have a table where the binding is different. 
So, each iconTab should have a context of the data like 'Env1', 'Env2' etc

Answer (score 1):

For the binding you suggested, your dataset may need to be modified a bit in order to achieve the requirement. PFB the code.

Controller

```
    loadDataSet: function () {
        var oMasterModel = this.getView().getModel("oMasterModel");
        var oDataSet = [{
            "IconTabName": "Env1",
            "Table": [{
                "name": "Person1",
                "runs": ["10", "20"]
            }, {
                "name": "Person2",
                "runs": ["0", "2"]
            }]
        }, {
            "IconTabName": "Env2",
            "Table": [{
                "name": "Person3",
                "runs": ["5", "25"]
            }, {
                "name": "Person4",
                "runs": ["20", "12"]
            }]
        }];
        oMasterModel.setData({
            allFilters: oDataSet
        });
        oMasterModel.refresh(true);
    }
```

View

```
<IconTabBar items="{oMasterModel>/allFilters}">
                    <items>
                        <IconTabFilter text="{oMasterModel>IconTabName}">
                            <Table items="{oMasterModel>Table}">
                                <columns>
                                    <Column>
                                        <Label text="Name"/>
                                    </Column>
                                    <Column >
                                        <Label text="Runs"/>
                                    </Column>
                                </columns>
                                <items>
                                    <ColumnListItem>
                                        <cells>
                                            <Text text="{oMasterModel>name}"/>
                                            <Select items="{oMasterModel>runs}">
                                                <core:Item text="{oMasterModel>}"/>
                                            </Select>
                                        </cells>
                                    </ColumnListItem>
                                </items>
                            </Table>
                        </IconTabFilter>
                    </items>
                </IconTabBar>
```

Comment: I can not prepare the model data as above as it is not fixed and may change.

Comment: I have edited the latest tried code. Please suggest

Comment: You edited the actual question. Can you let me know exactly what is it that you trying are to achieve here? Icontab filter and then tables bindings inside of it or just dynamic table bindings of sap.m.table